# Using a loop to create sequential records

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to write a routine which will take identify the most recent record in 'table 1' and compare it to a date which i store on another table ('table 2').  Once the comparison is made, I would like to create a routine (most likely using a loop) which will duplicate that same record from 'table 1' for each day falling between the range of the date in 'table 1' and the date in 'table 2'. For clarity purposes, if the date in 'table 1' is 4 September and the date identified in 'table 2' is 8 September, then i would like to create a routine that will duplicate the record in 'table 1' dated september 4,  4 times..   Sept 5, Sept 6, Sept7, and September 8.    Sorry if this is a bit confusing but I am a bit in the dark as to the best way to do this.  Thansk.

Comment: Just do it. Even if it's not the best way. If you don't know where to start, write pseudo code (as comments) then try to insert real code that matches your idea. Come back to SO when you have tried something and you have errors.

Comment: iDevlop. I completely agree with you and find that putting something down 'on the paper' is Always the best way to go and I have succeeded many times in the past with this strategy.  This time around however i sincerely don't know where to start and wonder if i may take myself down the wrong path if i am lucky enough to find one.

Answer (score 0):

Tred to create an example from your question please create a result like you would like it to look like (I don't really get what are you aiming for sorry)

```
**TABLE1**
ID  NAME    DATE
1   A1      2014-09-01
2   A2      2014-09-02
3   A3      2014-09-03
4   A4      2014-09-04
5   A5      2014-09-05
6   A6      2014-09-06
7   A7      2014-09-07
8   A8      2014-09-08
9   A9      2014-09-09
10  A10     2014-09-10

**TABLE2**
ID  NAME    DATE
1   B1      2014-09-03
2   B2      2014-09-04
3   B3      2014-09-06
4   B4      2014-09-08
5   B5      2014-09-10

**RESULT** (???)
T1.ID   T1.NAME T1.DATE T2.ID   T2.NAME T2.DATE
```

Comment: Jester, i just re-created this question and put a 100 point Bounty on it. It is called 'Writing a routine to create sequential records'. I put an example in it to make it more clear. I will delete this question shortly.